# Trouble using insertion sort with a Python list

Tags: python, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm given a text file that resembles the following...

```
hello 20
world 30
i'm 50
ok 20
```

I'm trying to use insertion sort to arrange the numerical part of the data. My code looks like the following...

```
def insertion_sort():
    filename = input('Enter filename: ')
    lst = []
    for line in open(filename):
        lst.append(int(line))
    print(lst)
    for index in range(1,len(lst)):
        value = lst[index]
        leftvalue = index -1
        while leftvalue >= 0 and lst[leftvalue] > value:
            if value < lst[leftvalue]:
                lst[leftvalue + 1] = lst[leftvalue]
                lst[leftvalue] = value
                leftvalue = leftvalue - 1
            else:
                break
    return lst == insertion_sort()
```

I'm getting the following error...
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Merchant_0 96918\n'`

I have tried using float in replacement with int but I can't convert strings to floats.

Comment: Well, what integer do you think that the string `Merchant_0 96918\n` should convert to?

Comment: It should convert to the number 96918

Comment: So what have you tried, in order to extract the part of the string that you want to convert to integer? What string-handling functions in Python do you know about?

Comment: We have covered most string functions except the strip function. I'm thinking of doing a bit of research on it to see how it'll help me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get an integer with :

`lst.append(int(line))`

if line contains, say 'world 30'

What do you try to obtain exactly ? If you want to get the numeric value, try :

`int(line.split(' ')[1])`

Or better (works even if there are multiple spaces in the input lines) :

```
import re
reobj=re.search('(\d+)$',line)
int(reobj.group(1))
```

The whole sorting process becomes :

```
import operator
import re

lines = {}
for line in open('tst.txt'):
    reobj=re.search('(\d+)$',line)
    int_key=int(reobj.group(1))
    value=line[0:reobj.start()]
    lines[int_key]=value

# See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value?rq=1
print "Sorted : ", sorted(lines.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```